# PHP mySQL query not working with variable as in field for SQL TIME type

Tags: php, mysql

One of the fields in the mysql database is 'TIME' type, formatted 'H:i:s'. When querying the database with the field value set, like:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_hour='06:00:00'", ARRAY_A));
```

Everything works great. But when I replace it with a variable like this:

```
$stime = '06:00:00';
$result = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_hour=$stime", ARRAY_A));
```

$result comes up empty. I've been messing about with the formatting of $stime, but am coming up empty.

Comment: Try to add single quotes around `$stime` in 2nd query.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing single quotes around `$stime` in your second query :

```
$stime = '06:00:00';
$result = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_hour='$stime'", ARRAY_A));
```